# Passing multiple items from a list into a function

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am relatively new to coding in python and currently trying to build my first web scraper.

I have created a function that puts all the links I want to get data from into a list.

['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com'...]

I now want to pass every single item in the list (url) to the function that actually gets the information.

I have tried to solve this with *args but I get the error that the urlopen() function only takes 3 arguments. So I have to find a way to pass each item/url individually into the function.

I know this is probably a quite easy thing to do but I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now and wasn't able to figure it our yet.

I would be very grateful if someone could point me into the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. There is some function that you want to run on every individual URL in a list that you obtained, is that correct?

Comment: Can't you just use a loop? I'm not sure I understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

A `list` is iterable, so you can access all of its contents via a `for` loop and parse them individually.

```
my_list ['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com']
for item in my_list:
    foo(item)
```

Comment: A Python list is iterable. It's not an iterator.

Comment: E.g., try `type(iter(list))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass each url to the urlopen() function, not pass all the urls at once.

```
my_urls = {'url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com'}

read_urls(url):
     urlopen(url)
     .... do some operation

for url in urls:
    read_urls(url)
```